# How to disable events span to another day in fullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using fullcalendar 3.8.0 with 4 types of view: listWeek, month, agendaWeek, agendaDay and trying to disable duplication of long events only in listWeek view, but can't find a settings or working approach.

I tried to describe eventDataTransform function for view like option (we called events - tasks cause we have task managment system)

```
calendar.fullCalendar({
  views:{
    listWeek: {
        eventDataTransform: function(task) {
            task.start = task.date_start;
            console.log('listWeek');
            return task;
        },
    }
  }
...
})
```

but this way not working. 
Also I tried to made condition in eventDataTransform function

```
eventDataTransform: function(task) {
    task.start = task.date_start;
    if  (calendar.fullCalendar('getView').name !='listWeek')
    {
       task.end = task.date_end;
     }
    return task;
},
```

And this seems to be working approach, but... when i select any other view after active month view eventDataTransform don't called. And listWeek view show me repeats of long events throught days till I changed date range to other month and back.

So i need to show tasks only once, on date thay created for listWeek, and normal behaviour for other views, because request from users, who use this view and recently delete tasks because of thinking thats they duplicate =_="
In example i printed current view.name to console from eventDataTransform function.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBS3j.gif)

Comment: If the users are not understanding the information that the event takes place over multiple days (despite it having identical description etc) then to me it sounds more like a training issue than anything you need to solve by complicated manipulation of the calendar. At most you could potentially consider including the event ID in the title so that it's clear they are all the same event since they have the same ID. Or, just don't provide the list view if they can't understand it.I realise you have to respond to user feedback but sometimes the best way to do that is just to educate people fully

Comment: P.s. if you make it so the list view only shows the event on its first day then that could just lead to other misunderstandings where people think the event really only takes one day, or they assume the rest of the time is available when it isn't. Or they will complain that the calendar isn't working properly because an event shows as three days in one view and one day in another! What users ask for is not always what they really want or need, often it's an instinctive reaction without considering all the implications. Maybe you should explore this in more depth to get the best solution

Comment: It sounds reasonable, I also think that I need to get deeper in understanding user stories. But on this subproject we use bunch of prototypes without long design stage, so I just have a task from my manager to make this version and test it on some users. And I think maybe somebody done this before or maybe i missed something in docs. If there is no simple way for solving this question, I'll take another direction, maybe provide other type of view or crerate another page for some task operations.

Comment: re-fetching the events from the server (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/refetchEvents) would cause eventDataTransform to execute again since it would re-process all the events. It's not very efficient to refetch the events every time you change the view, but it might be one way to try and solve the issue.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I add function wich called **refetchEvents** to **viewRender** option  and with conditioned **eventDataTransform** it works. I don't understand how i missed that i can force refetch....